# The total number of solutions (real) of equation: $2^x+3^x+4^x-5^x=0 ?$

Tags: functions

The total number of solutions (real) of equation: $2^x+3^x+4^x-5^x=0 ?$

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is easier to look at $(2/5)^x+(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x=1$.

Comment: By Laguerre's extension of Descartes' rule of sign, the number of real solution is $1$. See the statement and refs in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/887017/59379) to a similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given $$2^x+3^x+4^x=5^x\Rightarrow \underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{4.5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{3}{4.5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{4.5}\right)^x}_{\bf{Strictly\; decreasing \; fun.}} = \underbrace{\left(\frac{5}{4.5}\right)^x}_{\bf{Strictly\; increasing \; fun.}}$$

So these two function Intersect each other at exactly one point.

Comment: Then, we could use $4.999$ instead of $4.5$. Don't you think that André Nicolas's suggestion would even be easier since lhs will be decreasing and rhs a constant ?

Answer (score 0):

$$2^x+3^x+4^x=5^x$$

$${\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x} =1$$
$$y={\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x}$$ 
$$y=1$$
Since the function is always decreasing . It will meet $y=1$ only once .

Graph will make things more easier .[image]